# Android: InputStream

Tags: android, http-request

Existe uma maneira de eu trocar:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("xxx.html");
```

para:

```
InputStream is = ("http://www.xxx.com.br/xxx.html");
```

Talvez usando HttpURLConnection mas não sei como implementar.

Segue um pedaço do meu código onde estou querendo implementar isso:

```
try {
     InputStream is = getAssets().open("xxx.html");
     String data = getResultFromStream(is);

     WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
     ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     ws.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
     ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

     MyWebChromeClient chromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
     MyWebViewClient webViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();

     webView.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
     webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
     webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
     webView.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");

     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar

```
try {


 WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
 ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 ws.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
 ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

 MyWebChromeClient chromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
 MyWebViewClient webViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();

 webView.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
 webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
 webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
 webView.loadUrl("http://www.xxx.com.br/xxx.html");

 } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```